# Linq with date comparision not working

Tags: c#, linq, datetime-comparison

I need to compare two date ranges against a records list using LINQ, and for some reason I'm stuck badly. I am receiving date in string format which I am converting to DateTime. I know there is data within the specific date range in database so I should get records back.

```
public static string FilterStudentListInRelationToStaffByDateRange(
    string GivenStaffID, 
    string SelectFilterOption, 
    string FromDate, 
    string ToDate)
{ 
    var dt = DateTime.Parse(FromDate);
    // var fff = String.Format("{0:d/M/yyyy hh:mm:ss}", dt);

    var dt3 = DateTime.Parse(ToDate);
    //var fff3 = String.Format("{0:d/M/yyyy hh:mm:ss}", dt3);

    var x = (from b in queryList
            where b.RelationshipDateStart >= dt && b.RelationshipDateEnd <= dt3
            select b).ToList();
```

Comment: Show data in queryList and values of FromDate and ToDate.

Comment: Are `RelationshipDateStart` and `RelationshipDateEnd` actual date fields in your database, or are they some variant of `varchar`?

Comment: yes RelationshipDateStart and RelationshipDateEnd  are date fields

Comment: There's not enough information here for us to help you.  Please include an example of the data in `queryList` along with the values for `FromDate` and `ToDate`.  Tell us if it's a Linq-to-Objects or Linq-to-SQL or EF.   Show us the definition of the entities or class that `queryList` contains.

Comment: So are you getting a null list? Are you sure the DateTime are being parsed correctly?

Comment: How narrow is the time window you are testing with? Could there be timezone conversions happening?

Answer (score 1):

Date/time parsing can be annoying, specially if you handle different formats.

If you know the format, you can try using [`DateTime.ParseExact`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
string format = "d/M/yyyy hh:mm:ss";

try 
{
    var dt = DateTime.ParseExact(FromDate, format, provider);

    var dt3 = DateTime.ParseExact(ToDate, format, provider);

    var x = (from b in queryList
            where b.RelationshipDateStart >= dt && b.RelationshipDateEnd <= dt3
            select b).ToList();

}
catch (FormatException) 
{
     Console.WriteLine("Date is not in the correct format.");
}
```